# Google's webmaster tools saying invalid URL in sitemap

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I've recently made some big changes to my site and as a result, have had to change my sitemap. In doing so, I resubmitted my sitemap file only to see 3 errors reading invalid URL's. I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning or not that my sitemap file ins't actually a true XML file. Rather, it's a dynamic php file that the server is tricked into believing is an XML file thanks to modrewrite. This didn't matter last time as I had no sitemap errors. But, this time it is.

[image: Here is a pic of the error]

The actual sitemap can be found [here](http://www.sportannica.com/sitemap.xml)

The sitemap.php file starts like this:

```
<?php
require_once("model/functions.php");
require_once("model/model.php");
require_once("model/teams_array.php");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        <url>
            <loc>http://www.sportannica.com/quickpicks/</loc>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
            <priority>0.8</priority>
        </url>
       Continued ............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following problems:

- Your server return the wrong content type for the sitemap.  It returns `Content-Type: text/html` when it should return `Content-Type: application/xml`
- Your XML sitemap starts with a new line character.  This makes the XML document invalid.  When I run it through `xmllint` I get the following error: `sitemap.xml:2: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`

I doubt that the wrong content type is throwing Google off, but it is probably worth fixing.

The new line at the beginning of the document **should** be fixed.  If you are serving it via PHP it could be caused by PHP header information that you have in the document that doesn't get printed.    Once I remove the new line at the beginning, xmllint does not report any more problems.

Comment: I posted the beginning of the sitemap file in the hopes that it'll clear things up in regards to the error on line 2.

Comment: It is likely that one of the libraries in the require_once directives is causing the new-line to be printed.  I have seen extra new lines at the end of the file after the `?>` that cause the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the internet that I have at school wont let me connect to my remote server via ftp to overwrite the sitemap file. So, I won't be able to find out if the new file is valid using google's webmaster tools. But, as soon as I get home tonight I'll let you know how your advice has worked out. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I think the problem is with the files that are being required. What could it be in those files that's throwing an error? Could it be comment tags?